# Problem accessing Server variable in static function in C#

Tags: c#, static-functions

Im unable to access server/response variable in my static function. Can i access them in static function or should i include some namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current` object includes current `Server`, `Response`, `Request` etc instances.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a really hard time understanding your question, but is it possible that you are looking for [`HttpContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx)?

```
var context = HttpContext.Current;
// now you can use context.Request, context.Response, context.Server, etc.
```